# ¿Cómo sacar por la salida las cadenas en orden léxicográfico ascendente?

Tags: c, string, quicksort, str

Necesitaría ayuda para sacar por la salida el orden ascendiente de las cadenas en mayúsculas que yo meta como argumentos.

Hasta el momento he creado el siguiente código:

```
 #include <stdio.h>
  #include <ctype.h>

  int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {
    // Verificamos si se proporcionaron argumentos en la línea de comandos
    if (argc < 2) {
        printf("error: no arguments \n");
        return 1;
    }

    // Recorremos los argumentos, comenzando desde el segundo (argv[1])
    for (int i = 1; i < argc; i++) {
        char *arg = argv[i]; // Obtenemos el argumento actual
        // Convertimos cada carácter del argumento a mayúsculas e imprimimos
        while (*arg) {
            putchar(toupper(*arg));
            arg++;
        }
        printf("\n"); // Agregamos un salto de línea entre argumentos
    }

    printf("\n"); // Imprimimos un salto de línea al final
    return 0;
   
}
```

Si meto como argumentos ./ejercicio hola auto, me devuelve:

HOLA
AUTO

y necesitaría que fuese

AUTO
HOLA

Gracias de antemano por la ayuda.

Comment: Buenas, Ángela, [aquí](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/c-program-sort-array-names-strings/) puedes encontrar un ejemplo de como ordenar un array de strins en C

Comment: El algoritmo de ordenación no sería eficiente en este caso, ya que el código solo necesita invertir el orden de los argumentos y no ordenarlos.

Comment: En orden alfabético léxico ascendente, se comparan las letras de izquierda a derecha y, en caso de que los caracteres coincidan, la próxima verificación se realiza en el siguiente carácter. La forma correcta es `for (int i = argc - 1; i >= 1; i--)`

Comment: Bienvenida. La pregunta no es del todo clara. Por favor crea un [mre].